# MVC3 - How to dynamically set facebook app Id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, build

I have an MVC3 web app that uses a number of the facebook api calls. When I am testing I am using one facebook app Id but will use another in prod (this will be swapped in during the build).

Ideally I'd like to put the app Id in the web.config file to make swapping it during the build easy and so that the id is only in one place. However, I can't see an elegant way to get the id from the app.config into the multiple javascript functions that need it. I looked at reading it into a variable in the _AppStart.cshtml file but not sure that this is right as it means reading the value into a c# object and then passing that as a string to a javascript function that is called before each page loads and that smells a bit wrong.

I'm still learning javascipt so I'm not sure how this thing "should" be done. Any pointers would be great.

Matt

Comment: Why is this tagged with TeamCity?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've just come across this which deals with my question. I thought I'd exhausted google before asking this question but obviously not ;-)
[integrating-facebook-login-button-in-aspnet-mvc-4-application](http://blue-and-orange.net/articles/facebook/integrating-facebook-login-button-in-aspnet-mvc-4-application/)